# I want to grab the UID of clicked row using ajax from foreach loop php but getting all UID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the UID from an anchor tag which is the value of ID attribute of the anchor tag from a foreach loop PHP in ajax. But it only work once a time, when I click the anchor tag again then all the UIDs are grabbed in the ajax!

When I click on anchor tag then 1st I'm displaying a bootstrap 4 modal and in modal a textarea tag is present with a button and when I click button then I've to send uid and message again to the action.php page

This is my action.php code

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'fetchAllFeedback'){
    $feedback = $admin->fetchFeedback();
    $output = '';
    if($feedback){
        $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>FID</th>
                                        <th>UID</th>
                                        <th>User Name</th>
                                        <th>User E-Mail</th>
                                        <th>Subject</th>
                                        <th>Feedback</th>
                                        <th>Sent On</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';
    foreach ($feedback as $row) {
        $output .= '<tr>
                                    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['uid'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['subject'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['feedback'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['created_at'].'</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#" id="'.$row['uid'].'" title="Reply" class="text-primary feedbackReplyIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showReplyModal"><i class="fas fa-reply fa-lg"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>
                            </table>';
    echo $output;
    }
    else{
        echo '<h3 class="text-center text-secondary">:( No any feedback written yet!</h3>';
    }
}
```

This is feedback.php ajax code

```
$("body").on("click", ".feedbackReplyIcon", function(e){
    let uid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#feedback-reply-btn").click(function(e){
        if($("#feedback-reply-form")[0].checkValidity()){
            let message = $("#message").val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#feedback-reply-btn").val('Please Wait...');
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'assets/php/admin-action.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {uid:uid,message:message},
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#feedback-reply-btn").val('Send Reply');
                        $("#showReplyModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#feedback-reply-form")[0].reset();
                    }
                });
        }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I believe happens: Since you declare a click method inside another click method, the `uid` variable turns empty after the first use. It's generally a bad practice to stack events like this inside one another. Try changing your javascript to this:

```
        var uid;
        $("body").on("click", ".feedbackReplyIcon", function(e){
            uid = $(this).attr('id');
        });

        $("#feedback-reply-btn").click(function(e){
            if($("#feedback-reply-form")[0].checkValidity()){
                let message = $("#message").val();
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#feedback-reply-btn").val('Please Wait...');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'assets/php/admin-action.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {uid:uid,message:message},
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#feedback-reply-btn").val('Send Reply');
                        $("#showReplyModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#feedback-reply-form")[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This might still be less than optimal, I'm a bit unclear on how your elements are laid out, and I can't really test it out. Let me know on what happens - if it still doesn't work, try dumping out the variables in admin-action.php , and see what's in there.